# Pandas DataFrame - Plot linear regression line after getting regression value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, regression

I have the following DataFrame, a sample looking like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fxu03.png)

I got the regression via:

```
ADBE['Date'] = ADBE['Date'].values.astype(float)
model = pd.ols(y = ADBE['Close'], x = ADBE['Date'])
```

I get the following results:

[Regression results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lL4yI.png)`

I've tried plotting the results as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(model, ADBE['Close'])
```

I get the error message:

"x and y must have same first dimension"

I get that the regression result is simply a number (1 dimension) being contrasted against an array/dataframe (ADBE['Close'], and have tried several methods from stackoverflow to make the regression 2-dimensional. No luck. Anyone ever do this before with regression?

edit: I've also tried the following:

```
ols2 = np.polyfit(ADBE['Date'], ADBE['Close'], 1)

poly_ols2 = np.poly1d(ols2)
```

to which i get the error:

data type  not inexact

...for the OLS2 line. So either way I go (plotting regression, or just getting regression via polyfit in the first place) i'm getting an error

Answer (score 0):

> I get the error message:
>
> "x and y must have same first dimension"

It's because `model` is a pandas model object:

```
type(model)
pandas.stats.ols.OLS
```

`matplotlib` doesn't know what to do with this object in the way you're expecting it to. If you want to plot your data against the model's fitted values (for example) you should use: `model.y_fitted.values`. Below is a working example

```
from sklearn import datasets # toy dataset for this example
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
%matplotlib inline  # using jupyter notebook

iris = datasets.load_iris()
iris = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=iris.feature_names)

# note that pd.ols is deprecated and you should use 
# statsmodel or scikit learn for regression
model = pd.ols(y = iris['sepal length (cm)'], x = iris['sepal width (cm)'])

plt.scatter(y = model.y_fitted.values, x = iris['sepal length (cm)'])
plt.xlabel("sepal length (cm)")
plt.ylabel("OLS fitted values")
plt.show()
```

Comment: This is deprecated in the most recent Pandas